# wrong emacs configuration when trying to setup ggtags and flycheck with prelude

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp, flycheck

I am trying to fine-tune the setup for emacs with [emacs prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) included. 
I want to have as the default checker `cppcheck` for [flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) and activate [ggtags](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags) by default for [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/). I am coding mainly c++. It used to work before for `ggtags-mode` variable but now it seems not to work anymore.

```
(load "/home/user/.emacs.d/init.el")


(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  "Hook for all c derived modes."
  (c-add-style "my-style"
           '("stroustrup"
             (c-offsets-alist
              (innamespace . [0])
              (inline-open . 0)
              (inher-cont . c-lineup-multi-inher)
              (arglist-cont-nonempty . +)
              (template-args-cont . +))))
(setq c-default-style "my-style")
(when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode)
(ggtags-mode 1)
(flycheck-select-checker "c/c++-cppcheck"))
)


 (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      (my-c-mode-common-hook))
```

I have a warning that says `the following functions are not known to be defined: ggtags-mode, flycheck-select-checker`. But when loading the .emacs file is loaded, there are no errors.

Can anyone help me with the right way to make these 2 minor modes work correctly configured? For me it seems the right way to do it, but obviously I am missing something.

Comment: FYI: `flycheck-select-checker` needs a symbol as argument, not a string, i.e. `(flycheck-select-checker 'c/c++-cppcheck)`.

Comment: I corrected long ago. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `add-hook` wrongly: It takes a *function* as 2nd argument but you call your function there and so pass the value of `(flycheck-select-checker ..)` as the function. You will likely see an error in a C (C/Java/C++/AWK/...) mode.

What you need to do is `(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)`.

Also this code will never be executed:

```
(when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode)
  (ggtags-mode 1)
  (flycheck-select-checker "c/c++-cppcheck"))
```

because `'c-mode` is not derived of `'c++-mode`, I guess you want to check if the *current* major-mode is derived of `c++-mode`:

```
(when (derived-mode-p major-mode 'c++-mode)
  (ggtags-mode 1)
  (flycheck-select-checker "c/c++-cppcheck"))
```